# N1QL query for fetching a document where the expected field is a part of a list

Tags: database, couchbase, sql++

I am fairly new to N1QL queries. I have some documents like this.

```
{
   "object":[
      {
         "x":"a",
         "y":"b"
      },
      {
         "x":"c",
         "y":"d"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now I want to fetch all documents where "x"="a" in any of the list members. How can I achieve that in couchbase using N1Ql query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM bucketName WHERE ANY o IN object SATISFIES o.x='a' END
```

`ANY` and `SATISFIES` are collections operators, and there are other ones you can use, including `EVERY`. You can read more about it in the [Couchbase documentation on Collection Operators](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/collectionops.html).